# momentjs: show first day of month 7 days into month

Tags: momentjs

Is it possible to use momentjs to return the first day of the current month 7 days into the current month.  I have a parameter that I want to rollover to the first day of the month after the 7th day of the month.  For example, I want it to show October 1, 2018 from October 8th to November 7th.  On the 8th of November I'd like it to show November 1, 2018.  So, essentially on the 8th day each month rollover to show the first day of the current month.

I have successfully used momentjs to give me the first day of the current month using:

().startOf('month')

I know it's a weird question, but it's related to our business rules.

Answer (score 1):

`moment().subtract(7,'d').startOf('month')`